# Passing a file path as a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, file, dynamic, database-partitioning

I'm trying to add a file to a file group in order to create a partition in SQL Server. When I pass in a hardcoded file path to the the filename, the code works. But when I use a variable for the file path, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near @FilePath or Unexpected symbol @FilePath

This is my code:

```
USE StudentRepository

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @FilePath NVARCHAR(MAX) = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\",
            @FileName NVARCHAR(MAX) = "FirstTerm2020",
            @FileExt NVARCHAR(MAX) = ".NDF";
    DECLARE @count INT = 0;

    ALTER DATABASE StudentRepository   
    ADD FILE   
    (  
        NAME = 'FirstTerm2020',  
        FILENAME = @FilePath + @FileName + @FileExt,  --Error here!
        SIZE = 5MB,  
        MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
        FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
    )  
    TO FILEGROUP  FirstTerm2020
END
```

When I pass a hardcoded file path to the filename, it works and creates the required partitions. as below

```
--Code omitted for brevity
FILENAME =  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\FirstTerm2020.NDF"  --No error!
```

Please I need some help. How do I pass a file path as a variable?

Comment: dynamic SQL .....

Comment: Have you read the [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) File and Filegroup Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options) documentation yet? None of the options accept values from variables, they're all literals. If you need to supply these paths dynamically then you will need to construct Dynamic SQL queries.

Comment: Generate a text to execute a dynamic SQL

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: double quotes are for object names in SQL, not string literals

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - Please can you demonstrate your answer with an example. I don't understand how to use sqlcmd. Dynamic SQL does not work either, I have tried it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn- Single quotes are also not working that is why I decided to use double quotes instead.

Comment: @AwarDenen https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140721/howto-avoid-textdata-of-trace-gets-truncated

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem. I create a dynamic sql and passed the filepath variable like this.

```
USE StudentRepository

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @FilePath NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\',
            @FileName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SecondTerm2022',
            @FileExt NVARCHAR(MAX) = '.NDF';
    DECLARE @count INT = 0;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    ALTER DATABASE StudentRepository ADD FILEGROUP ' + @FileName + ';

    ALTER DATABASE StudentRepository   
    ADD FILE   
    (  
        NAME = '+ @FileName + ',  
        FILENAME = ''' + @FilePath + @FileName + @FileExt + ''',
        SIZE = 5MB,  
        MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
        FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
    )  
    TO FILEGROUP  '+ @FileName
END

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

My major problem was that I was ommitting the three single quotes near @FilePath